# Blocking socket, possible to solve with multiprocessing?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to learn some basic socket programming in python. What i would like to do is have a seperate thread that activliy listens for network activity while my main program does something else.

What I don't understand is why the while(True) loop in the code below never runs. Should it not be on a seperate thread from the socket?

```
import socket
import multiprocessing

def waitForConnection():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    port = 8000
    address = ''
    server_socket.bind((address, port))
    server_socket.listen(0)
    client_socket, client_ip = server_socket.accept()
    client_conn = client_socket.makefile(mode='rwb')

process = multiprocessing.Process(target=waitForConnection())
process.start()


#main program
while(True):
    print("I never reach this line when no client is connected")
```

Comment: Have you tried hitting ctrl+c and looking at the traceback to see where your program is hanging? Also, you can't really use `multiprocessing.Process()` with sockets like that – the subprocess will own the socket, not your main script.

Comment: `target=waitForConnection()` calls the function *right now*, *in the current thread*, and uses its return value (which is None) as the target to run in another process.  Remove those parentheses, so you're actually passing the function.

Comment: AKX oh that's ok i was planning on having the subprocess be seperate from the main script.

@jasonharper omg i can't believe i missed that. Well guess that solves it.